# 1d array send into 2d array

Tags: arrays, c, string

I have a this polynomial in a array;

x+3x^3-5+x^7

for example;

a[2]=3

a[0]=x;

```
char arr[10][10];
        int m;
        i=0;
        j=0;
        while(i<10){
            if(a[j]=='\n'){
                break;
                }
            for(m=0;m<10;m++){
                if(a[j]=='+' || a[j]=='-'){
                    break;
                    }
                    else{
                    arr[i][m]=a[j];
                    j++;
                        }
                        
                        }
                        i++;
                        }
                        printf("%c",arr[2][0]);     
        
        
                return 0;
                }
```

I want to this array send into 2d strin array.(+ and - without).
I use this code but it doesnt work.How can I fix it.Thanks...

Comment: Why you want to put it in a 2D array if it fits in a simple one-dimentional array? How do you want the 2D array to be filled?

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't really a question. ***How*** doesn't it work? What is the code supposed to be doing? What does it actually do? If you get build errors then please [edit] your question and add them. If you get unexpected result then please [edit] your question to add the input given, the expected output, and the actual output. And please try to create a proper [mcve] to show us.

Comment: @Davide Because then I have to calculate the value of the polynomial using the values in this string.(using sscanf) for example, if there is 3x^3 in the string, the program should dial it to 3*x*x*x.Do you think it's more appropriate for me to use a 1D array?

Comment: @chrwbacca all right, now it makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to write the program for you, I just give you a guide for the crucial part:

Read the input into the 1D array a[N]

Find length of array with strlen

Run a for loop from i=0 till i<len

Every time you find that a[i] == '^'  you run a loop from j=0 to j<a[i+1]

In this nested loop you set array[row][j] = a[i-1]

You need to initialize row to 0 and you need to increment it after exit the nested loop. Then in the outer loop you need an `else if( a[i] !='+' && a[i] != '-')` in which you just set array[row][0]=a[i]. Don't forget to always put a '\0' at the end of every row, so at the end you can easily print the 2D array.

I could say more but I leave it to you to make the program. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Please take some time to think about the condition `a[j] != '+' || a[j] != '-'`...

Lets say that `a[j]` is `'+'`. Then `a[j] != '+'` will be false, and that's good. But it will also mean that `a[j] != '-'` will be *true*, and that's not so good. Same thing with if `a[j]` is `'-'`, but the opposite for the two conditions.

If you study [De Morgans' laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) you will learn that the opposite of `a[j] == '+' || a[j] == '-'` is *not* `a[j] != '+' || a[j] != '-'` as you've written, but rather `a[j] != '+' && a[j] != '-'`.

Comment: That's all right, but it doesn't answer the OP question

Comment: @Davide Since the question really is "it doesnt work.How can I fix it." this could be the answer the OP is looking for. It's definitely a problem.

Comment: 'char arr[10][10];
  int m;
  i=0;
  j=0;
  while(i<10){
   if(a[j]=='\n'){
    break;
    }
   for(m=0;m<10;m++){
    if(a[j]=='+' || a[j]=='-'){
     j++;
     break;
     }
     else{
     arr[i][m]=a[j];
     j++;
      
      }
      
      }
      i++;
      }
      printf("%c %c",arr[2][0],a[3]);'

Comment: As I understand it, this is a more accurate approach, but it still lacks one.